# Determine the database name inside of stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure in Mysql and I was wondering if there is a command that I can get and store the name of the database that this stored procedure lives in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about DATABASE() ?

(This text is just filler)

Answer (score -1):

Your Question is wrong?..Your actual question is you have created a stored procedure inside the databases...not how to retrieve the procedure inside the database?
Ans: To know the created procedure:

```
mysql:\> show procedure status;  //to know the procedure name..sam4 function show function staus;
mysql:\> show use create procedure emptab.test1 //emptab is database name,test1 is the procedure..
```